# dreamweaver regex replacement fails when newline used in search pattern

Tags: regex, newline, dreamweaver

I am trying to use

```
\nx
```

as the pattern
and

```
\ny
```

as the replacement
in Dreamweaver CS6.  The file is located on a Win7 machine and is put to a CentOS6.4 server for use.

The idea is to replace an x at the start of a line with a y.  Dreamweaver finds the pattern ok but no matter what I choose as a replacement, nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this file is using \r\n (carriage return and newline) for a line delimiter rather than only \n (newline) as was expected.  The solution is to use

```
(\r?\n)x
```

as the pattern and

```
$1y
```

as the replacement.

Works like a champ.  The file source lives on a Win7 laptop but is put to a UNIX box (CentOS 6.4) for actual use.

Also, a big thank you to commenter for suggestion to make \r conditional so pattern will handle both Linux / UNIX and Windows.

Comment: You may improve the expression by using `(\r?\n)x`, that way you will match both linux/windows newlines :)